# Django - formset with crispy forms - missing management form data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, formset

I'm trying to render this form set:

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    model=Product,
    fields='__all__',
    extra=5,
)

class ProductFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_tag = False
        self.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                'productCategory',
                'name',
                'measurement_unit',
            )
        )
        self.render_required_fields = True
```

with this view:

```
def product_create(request):
    helper = ProductFormSetHelper()
    context = {
        'helper': helper,
        'title': 'Nuovi Prodotti',
    }
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = ProductFormSet(queryset=Product.objects.none())
        context['formset'] = formset

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST)
        context['formset'] = formset
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Prodotti aggiunti correttamente', fail_silently=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('warehouse:products_list'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'warehouse/product_create.html', context)
    return render(request, 'warehouse/product_create.html', context)
```

and this template:

```
{% extends "masterpage.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block headTitle %}
<title>Nuovo Prodotto</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block contentHead %}
{% endblock %}

{% block contentBody %}
{% load document_tags %}
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<FORM method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{ title }}
    </div>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% crispy formset helper %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-left" value="SALVA">
</FORM>

{% endblock %}
```

Problem is that when I submit the form I get the: ValidationError: management form data are missing! First of all, using crispy forms the management data should be included, second even if I explicitly call with the tag, I still get the ValidationError.

in Every forum I searched online, everyone was missing the management form tag, so I have no clue on what could be wrong....

Any idea?

thank you very much

C

Answer (score 0):

in your Post method you didnt include the "queryset"

```
formset = ProductFormSet(queryset=Product.objects.WHATEVER_YOU_CHOOSE, request.POST)
```

and for crispy forms

```
                   {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 

                   <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ formset|crispy }}
                        {{ formset.management_form }}
                      
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-left" value="SALVA">
                   </form>
```

and because you are not working in get_context_data fucntion, just keep it simple

```
context = {'formset':formset}
```

**Exemple from the docs**

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import Author

def manage_authors(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name', 'title'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AuthorFormSet(
            request.POST, request.FILES,
            queryset=Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='O'),
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # Do something.
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet(queryset=Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='O'))
    return render(request, 'manage_authors.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not change anything. Plus using {{ formset|crispy }} does not allow me to use the helper to format the form ( which would display all horizontal field).

Comment: By the way, with: `{% crispy formset helper%}` makes the management data automatically. I just double checked in the source code of the web page. This means that they are not missing, but they have been corrupted....which raises the question....how the hell this happened???

Comment: also @taha-maatof, why do I need to specify the queryset if I'm working with Post data? I seems counter-intuitive, but I could be wrong

Comment: i added something to my answer from the docs , to clarify the POST Method https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/, hope it helps

Comment: And for the template i use exactly what i wrote in the answer, it works fine, i'm sorry i dont know why it doesn't work in your case

Comment: Solved the problem, I'll post the solution. Thank you anyway for you help @taha-maatof :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help others. Since I'm having troubles configuring the thousand separator, I tried to change the input.html widget in /templates/django/forms/widgets by adding the |intcomma filter.
This altered the management form data ( one field is set to 1000 by default ), thus corrupting the whole form.